# A more concise way to create an array, fill it, then return it?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a method to scan items:

```
def scan(*items)
  scanned_items = []
  items.each { |item| scanned_items << item }
  scanned_items
end
```

I see (and use) the guts of this method often - that is, make an empty array, put some stuff in it, and then return the array.  Is there a more concise way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is nothing to do:

```
items.dup
```

for simple stuff:

```
items.map(&:simple)
```

really complex operations:

```
[].tap do |result|
  items.each do |item|
    # complex conditions, loops, etc
    result << item
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This concrete example can be simplified to this

```
scanned_items = items.dup
```